# Host ASP.NET 4.0 in IIS 6 on Windows 2003 x64

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, application-pools, windows-server-2003-r2

I want to host an ASP.NET 4.0 web application in IIS 6 on Windows 2003 R2 SP2 x64.

Is this even possible? I have the following under `C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework`

- 1.0.3705
- 1.1.4322
- 2.0.50727
- 3.0
- 3.5
- 4.0.30319

and in `C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64` the same except 1.0 and 1.1.

IIS 6 runs in 32 bit mode but there is no ASP.NET tab in the properties screen of the website. So I can't switch frameworks and don't know what frameworks runs in what application pool.

**EDIT** have tried what GregD suggested. That gave me back the tab in IIS so that I could set the proper framework for the website, but it gave me the following in the eventlog when I tried to start the application pool:

*Could not load all ISAPI filters for site/service. Therefore startup aborted.*

After a quick googling, I found this: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/service-unavailable-could-not-load-all-isapi-filters-for-siteservice-therefore-startup-aborted/

Which kind of puts me in a circle. Enabling and removing the 64 bit setting in the metabase.xml file.

Because **aspnet_regiis -i** told me that it couldn't work because IIS was in a 64-bit setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it.

On your web service extensions folder (in IIS Manager) are your asp.net extensions enabled for the different versions?

**Edited to add**:  To get your tab back try this:

1) Stop the IIS Admin service (and any services that depend on it)

2) Open C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml in notepad or your favorite XML Editor. *DELETE* the line that reads ‘Enable32BitAppOnWin64=”TRUE”’

3) Restart IIS

Comment: yes it's all enabled. but i can't switch frameworks, the tab is not there

Comment: Is this running on VMWare by chance?

Comment: Hello GregD, it's not running on VMWare, just a normal win 2003 x64 install. but i cannot switch .net frameworks in iis.

Comment: Editing the MetaBase.xml file worked perfectly for me.  Thanks

Comment: It gave me my option back to select asp.net 4 but then got this in the eventlog: 
Description:
Could not load all ISAPI filters for site/service.  Therefore startup aborted. will take a closer look tomorrow :) thanks!

Comment: i tried this: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/service-unavailable-could-not-load-all-isapi-filters-for-siteservice-therefore-startup-aborted/ but aspnet_regiis.exe -i told me that it can't be done because iis was in 64 bit mode. so i had to set the metabase setting back? i have the idea that i am in a circle. will update the question above

Answer (score 0):

It works now. It seems that I can't have the option in IIS to switch frameworks.

I did:

```
C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319>cscript c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET /w3svc/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 True
```

and then

```
C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable
```

and it worked! As I said, no ASP.NET tab is visible in IIS, but it works!